# Short sci fi book, two races, two regions, tiny planet, refugees

Tags: story-identification

The planet has two regions and is so small that only a few beings can fit in the smaller region. All the rest of them are refugees in the bigger region. The book is maybe 200 pages max.

Comment: Can you remember anything else about this novel? There are a lot of science fiction books with a planet divided into two regions.

Comment: Got asked today in the bookstore. It's actually shorter, maybe 70-90 pages. One large region, one tiny region - maybe 6 of one race can fit into their own region and so the rest are refugees in the larger region. That's all the information I was given.

Comment: Well we found it - not technically sci-fi but certainly fantastical - The Brief and Frightening Reign of Phil by George Saunders.

Comment: [Downbelow Station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downbelow_Station) by C. J. Cherryh had twos races and refugees were a central theme.  But not a tiny planet.

Answer (score 10):

It's [The Brief and Frightening Reign of Phil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brief_and_Frightening_Reign_of_Phil) by George Saunders. We found it! :)

> The story focuses on the border disputes between the countries of
>   Inner and Outer Horner, the former of which is "so small that only one
>   Inner Hornerite at a time could fit inside, and the other six Inner
>   Hornerites had to wait their turns to live in their own country while
>   standing very timidly in the surrounding country of outer Horner."
>
> Phil, an embittered Outer Hornerite, decides that the puny Inner
>   Hornerites do nothing but stand around very close together solving
>   math proofs all day, and have to stretch one at a time every morning.
>   Seen as an evil threat to the leisure of the five Outer Hornerites,
>   they are understood as abusing the vast good will that they have
>   received courtesy of the Outer Hornerites. As they stand in the
>   short-term residency zone in Outer Horner, they wait their turn to
>   reenter their country. So Phil, gaining the support of the other Outer
>   Hornerites and hiring two giants as his personal policy enforcers,
>   begins to tax the Inner Hornerites for staying in his country. He
>   settles in the end to accept the disassembling of the Inner Hornerites
>   as sufficient payment. The story chronicles Phil's tyrannical rise to
>   power and his attempted Inner Hornerite genocide.

Comment: Very nice! If you are good at answering [tag:story-identification] questions,  we have a lot....

Comment: :) In about 48 hours, you should be able to accept your own answer.